# Google analytics funnel visualization

Tags: google-analytics

I created a funnel  visualization on Google analytics, but although all the URLs are entered accurately, the funnel shows a 100% flow rate, which is impossible. Is there anything that I am missing or haven't set up ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Funnel Visualization report, you may see a 100% exit rate from your first step or a 100% continuation rate if multiple steps contain the same pages or screens. Keep in mind that funnel steps accept regular expressions. For example, if your first step is your homepage—i.e., '/'—then it actually matches all pages that contain or begin with '/'. In this example, you'd see a 100% exit rate from that first step. To resolve this issue, adjust the [regular expressions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324) you use for your funnel steps.